# Iptables masquerade not working on Debian VM

Tags: iptables, nat

I have a VM in VirtualBox with Debian 10 and I'm trying to NAT masquerade it's output interface (enp0s8) so that it's clients (VMs connected to it) can access the Internet.

All interfaces in the system have an IP. I've already enabled forwarding with:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

And then I executed:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s8 -j MASQUERADE
```

However, whenever I execute the above, the following happens:

[image]

And no matter how many times I `iptables --flush -t nat` and repeat the process, the result is always the same. The rule I want to apply is never saved properly and the client's IPs are never masked.

What is the issue here? Almost all tutorials say this is the correct way for masquerading.
I've also tried using nftables, without success.

Answer (score 1):

It is already showing the right output. To show the rules with the interface details, you need to use,

```
iptables -t nat -L -n -v
```

And btw, if you have setup NAT networking, it is already taken care to connect outside.

And have you set the default gateway of your clients to this box?

Comment: Yes, I have a default gateway. Everything works now, I just rebooted the system.